# Determine if an SQLite 3 database is read-only - without using sqlite3_db_readonly()

Tags: sqlite

I need to know whether an SQLite database I opened is read-only. I have to use a slightly outdated version of SQLite, where there is no sqlite3_db_readonly() yet. The implementation of sqlite3_db_readonly() uses private calls, so it cannot be copied to the client code. What can be done, besides checking if the file is writable before opening?

EDIT: the version is 3.7.0.1.

EDIT 2: I am using the amalgamation.

Comment: What version of sqlite are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You probably already got your hands on the `sqlite3` "Database Connection Handle" object. It is defined in [sqliteInt.h](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/artifact/d9e42f2029d4c526f9ba960bda1980ef17429c30):

```
struct sqlite3 {
  sqlite3_vfs *pVfs;            /* OS Interface */
  int nDb;                      /* Number of backends currently in use */
  Db *aDb;                      /* All backends */
  int flags;                    /* Miscellaneous flags. See below */
  int openFlags;                /* Flags passed to sqlite3_vfs.xOpen() */
  int errCode;                  /* Most recent error code (SQLITE_*) */
  int errMask;                  /* & result codes with this before returning */
```

You can then test for read-only with the `openFlags` member against `O_RDWR`.

```
#define O_RDONLY        00000000
#define O_WRONLY        00000001
#define O_RDWR          00000002
```

For sure this is not the same as the newer `sqlite3_db_readonly()`, but it might be enough in your context.

**Edit**

Following up on your comment you can do the following to "future-proof" your code:

- check if the `sqlite3` struct varies between 3.7.0.1 and the first version that supports `sqlite3_db_readonly()`
- use some macros to map the right dupe of the `sqlite3` struct (or the right offset of `openFlags`) with the corresponding 3.x.y.z version since `SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER` is defined in sqlite3.h.
- starting with the version that supports `sqlite3_db_readonly()` just invoke it.

Note that a database will be opened read-only if its file can only be opened for read, whether the sqlite3_open_v2 function is used with the `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` or not. So in addition to the aforementioned `openFlags` you'll also need to separately verify if the file can be opened read-only. The C API provides the function `xAccess` in the `sqlite3_vfs` struct. I'm guessing that this work whether your application already has a lock on the db file. See  http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the amalgamation, so unfortunately I cannot include the declaration of `struct sqlite3` in the client code to examine `openFlags`. I can, of course, modify the amalgamation itself, but I was hoping there was another way.

Comment: Are you asking if I can use an offset, instead of referencing the struct member by name? I can, but if `struct sqlite3` changes due to an update to a newer version of sqlite, the behavior might become undefined.

Comment: I augmented my answer to deal with other versions.

Comment: I am trying to detect whether a database is opened as read-only - for any reason. So yes, both.