# Determine if an sqlite3 database is read-only

Tags: python, sqlite

I'd like to open an sqlite3 database, and immediately check that it is not opened read-only. Since I know I'll need to write to it, I want to return an error immediately at start-up, and not have to wait until a later time when the program first tries to do a write.

I see there is a sqlite3 [C API function `sqlite3_db_readonly()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/db_readonly.html). Is it possible to access this function from the Python API? Or is there some other way to check if a database is read-only from the Python API?

Comment: You have to [go to lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205744/opening-sqlite3-database-from-python-in-read-only-mode) to open it as read-only. Why would you not know it was read-only?

Comment: @PeterWood If the DB file doesn't have write permissions, then it will be opened in read-only mode.

Comment: You could use [**`os.access`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.access), e.g: `os.access(db, os.W_OK)`.

Comment: @PeterWood "I/O operations may fail even when `access()` indicates that they would succeed, particularly for operations on network filesystems which may have permissions semantics beyond the usual POSIX permission-bit model." I don't want something that works except for the times when it doesn't.

Comment: You can tailor it to your situation. If you want something bulletproof for all situations then you need to consider that permissions can change, that writing can fail for other reasons, and you should be handling exceptions anyway. I guess you could access `sqlite3_db_readonly` from the DLL using `ctypes.CDLL`. Also, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154978/determine-if-an-sqlite-3-database-is-read-only-without-using-sqlite3-db-readon)

Comment: Yes, I do want something bulletproof for all situations. I aim to avoid writing crappy code.

Comment: Three and a half years later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no and yes.see the source code of the python standard library sqlite3.

```
rc = sqlite3_open_v2(database, &self->db,
                        SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE |
                       (uri ? SQLITE_OPEN_URI : 0), NULL);
```

this means even if you didn't set the `uri`,it will open in read-only mode when the file in read-only mode.and search in the code.there are no invoke of `sqlite3_db_readonly()`.so you cannot do it by library sqlite3.

but yes,there are other library,for example[APSW](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/).the code

```
`static PyObject*
Connection_readonly(Connection *self, PyObject *name)
{
  int res=-1;
  res=sqlite3_db_readonly(self->db, PyBytes_AS_STRING(utf8name));
}`
```

then read the DOC,just call `Connection.readonly(name)`

Answer (score 7):

Apart from other possibilities mentioned, you can just try writing to it.  For example, if the `user_version` of the database is 0 (which it will be unless you have changed it), issue `pragma user_version=0;`.  This will have no effect if the database is writable, but will result in an error if the database is read-only.